# Howto encrypt one block with openSSL and C++

Tags: c++, openssl, aes

I want to encrypt a single block using the openSSL implementation of AES-Rijndael. However, I can't compile my program as soon as I use an openSSL function.

The compiler says the following:

```
g++ aes.cpp -o application
/tmp/ccnmjLvT.o: In function `RunRijndael()':
aes.cpp:(.text+0x25c): undefined reference to `AES_set_encrypt_key'
aes.cpp:(.text+0x273): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong? Apparently the library is included because AES_KEY seems to be no problem. But why can't I use any functions?

Here is some example code to demonstrate my problem:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <openssl/aes.h>

using namespace std;

int BLOCKSIZE = 16;

//Hashes a string into an unsigned char.
unsigned char MyHash8(std::string data) {
    const int MOD_HASH = 255;
    unsigned char a = 1, b = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < data.length(); ++index) {
        a = (a + data[index]) % MOD_HASH;
        b = (b + a) % MOD_HASH;
    }
    return (b << 4) | a;
}

//Hash-Function to generate an array of BLOCKSIZE length from given string.
unsigned char* GenerateBlock(std::string seed) {
    unsigned char* block = new unsigned char[BLOCKSIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < BLOCKSIZE; i++) {
        block[i] = MyHash8(seed);
        seed += block[i] / 2 + 1;
    }
    return block;
}

/* 
 * This function generates a 16 byte secret and a 16 byte plaintext.
 * Then it creates the AES encryption key and with that it encrypts
 * the plaintext block.
 */
void RunRijndael() {
    unsigned char* userKey = GenerateBlock("test");
    int bits = BLOCKSIZE*8;
    AES_KEY* key;

    unsigned char* plaintextBlock = GenerateBlock("randomPlaintext");
    unsigned char* ciphertextBlock;


    /*
     * The compiler has problems with this part!
     * 
     * g++ aes.cpp -o application
     * /tmp/ccnmjLvT.o: In function `RunRijndael()':
     * aes.cpp:(.text+0x25c): undefined reference to `AES_set_encrypt_key'
     * aes.cpp:(.text+0x273): undefined reference to `AES_encrypt'
     * collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
     */
    AES_set_encrypt_key(userKey, bits, key);
    AES_encrypt(plaintextBlock, ciphertextBlock, key);
}

int main() {
    RunRijndael();
}
```

Comment: _"Apparently the library is included because AES_KEY seems to be no problem. But why can't I use any functions?"_ You don't include libraries; you link against them. `AES_KEY` is just a typedef located in `aes.h`. To use the AES functions you need to also compile the necessary files from crypto/aes.

Comment: Thank you! :) I got it to compile with "g++ aes.cpp openssl-1.0.2d/crypto/aes/aes_core.c openssl-1.0.2d/crypto/aes/aes_misc.c -o application". But it was quite a hassle finding out what files I needed. Isn't there an easier way?